# Why does the default image for an image CCK field not show in a view?

Tags: views, 6, media, entities

I have a File/Image CCK field with a default image set and the Use default image checkbox is checked.
I am rendering this field in a view- but the default image does not show for nodes where an image has not been uploaded.

How do I get the default image to show in a view?

Ive tried re-uploading the image, re-setting the checkbox, clearing cache. FYI, if I do upload an image, it does show in the view.

Any further ideas?

Comment: This works here for me with Views 3 at least.  One thing to note that might be different:  if you add a field to a node type and there are nodes that are already created, these "pre-new field nodes" won't have the default set until you resave them.

Comment: BTW, Im using Views 2.

Comment: Jimajamma, just tried that re-saving idea but it didnt work. The image field did exist before creation anyway.

Comment: Perhaps a work around could be achieved by rendering some alternative HTML in the view if the image field is empty?

Comment: If Views 2 has 'rewrite when empty' logic like Views 3, most definitely. Alas, I don't have a testbed to check if that is the case.  But if it did/does, it would be an found when you click on the gear to change the other options of that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So my solution was to use Customfield to write some PHP to check if the image field is empty. If it is, then I output some HTML to render a default image. I had to hard-code the image URL which is not ideal.